# Printwriter ; i can send only first of my commands to Serial of Arduino

Tags: java, arduino, serial-port, printwriter

here is my problem. i am making a machine that java program controls arduino by Serial.read() function of arduino.
ın order to communicate with arduino i used "Printwriter and get outputstream".
my question is: "why i can send just one command when i clicked the button? I want to send that each listmember in that arraylist one by one"
how can i do it please help

```
private void otomatikmoddenemebutonuActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                        
       
try {
    
    BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("E:\\DenemeOtomatikKomutlar.txt"));
    ArrayList<String> listOfLines = new ArrayList<>();
    String line = bufReader.readLine(); 
    while (line != null) {
        listOfLines.add(line); line = bufReader.readLine(); 
    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(chosenPort.getOutputStream());
    
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfLines.size(); i++) {
        
        output.println(listOfLines.get(i));
        output.flush();
        
                 otodenemeTF.setText(listOfLines.get(3));
    
        }
    }
 bufReader.close();
    
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(PaintMixer_JogModu.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(PaintMixer_JogModu.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} 
}
```

Comment: otodenemeTF.setText(listOfLines.get(i));

Comment: i found a temporary solution to add a delay to for cycle.

try {
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(PaintMixer_JogModu.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }